# How to understand allotment of memory adress to a variable(int)?

Tags: python, variables, memory

I was reading about how Python manages variables. The book said that the integer literals are stored in memory at contiguous memory addresses.. By that means, if 15 is stored at (x) then 16 is stored at (x+32). an so on.

So if we declare something like:

```
a = 15
```

It simply refers to a memory location with the value 15. And if after that we declare

```
a = 16
```

it starts pointing to the adjacent block representing 16.

But at that I realized that must be a waste of memory. I understood out of that that all memory addresses are filled with number from minimum value of int to max value of int.

I need to know why Python implements a memory heavy program? Or maybe I am misunderstanding it? And if I am wrong at understanding it, how does Python give contiguous memory blocks and how does it allot memory address?

Comment: What about that made you think that a literal was stored anywhere in memory if it was unused? For example, a contiguous memory block with all literals used in the program in sorted order would satisfy that explanation and not waste any memory, right?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz See, that was something I thought of. but even sorting in that order would mean that those memory addresses  cannot be used for other things. So it would still be as if that memory was being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your book is wrong. `int`s are not stored in contiguous memory addresses, they're allocated objects like anything else. Small `int`s might be contiguous (CPython caches small `int`s in bulk, so they're more likely to be contiguous), but that's an implementation detail at best.

The CPython small `int` cache only applies to values between -5 and 256, so it's not wasting a lot of memory on them. All other `int` values are created and destroyed like normal objects, on demand, so:

```
x = 256
y = x + 1
z = x + 1
```

assigns completely different object references to `y` and `z`.

Comment: Oh get it . Thanks.

Comment: One point more why is y and z pointing to different locations but if we declare( y =257) and (z=257) why both have same address?

Comment: @dawoodmansoor: Another implementation detail. Constant coalescence applies in some cases, where constants are stored in a function's table of constants, and if the same constant is seen twice, they remove the duplicate from the table and just use the one copy. Again, since this is an implementation detail, don't rely on it.